# Don't call onCreateOptionsMenu in Fragment on largelayout

Tags: android, fragment, options-menu

I have 3 `Fragment`s which, in a normal (small) layout are all in separate Activities. They should provide an optionsmenu in the small layout.

In the large layout, I have the 3 fragments in one Activity, causing the menu to fill with the buttons inflated by all three fragments. How can I prevent this, and only let the Activity inflate the optionsmenu, while still holding the functionality on smaller devices?

-Edit-

So each Fragment uses the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Some code */
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    /* Some code */
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
}
```

When all three Fragments are shown, all Fragments execute `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and all items appear three times.
What I want is for the parent `Activity` to take the responsibility of creating the options menu.

Comment: You should add some relevant code for where you create the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each Fragment I would build the entire menu. What I've done is, to add in the Fragments only their specific menu items, and in the parent Activity I would build the general items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `isVisible()` method on each `Fragment` to dynamically check which is being displayed and then add appropriately within the Activity.